# .Net Textbox returns "undefined" value when trying to access from Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've got this textbox which I'm trying to access in Javascript/jQuery:

```
<asp:Textbox ID="txtChosenTime" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>
```

I've tried a handful of variations on:

```
var TestVal = $("<%=txtChosenTime.ClientID%>");
console.info(TestVal.value);
```

Also for example:

```
var TestVal = $("<%=txtChosenTime.ClientID%>").value;
console.info(TestVal);
```

Or without the `$`

I'm getting `undefined` as the value, if not an error with some of the other variations.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are you running your JS code somewhere which the ASP.Net logic will be interpreted? If so, then it should work. If not (such as running it from an external .js file) then that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have jQuery installed and working?

To select a element by control "id", then you use the format

```
 $("#MyControl")
```

Note the number "#" or so called pound sign.

and to select by class, you just use

```
 $(".MyClass")
```

so, in your case?

say like this:

```
        <asp:Textbox ID="txtChosenTime" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" class="mycool" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" class="mycool" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="run my js code"
            OnClientClick="myjscode();return false;"
            />


        <script>

            function myjscode() {

                // select control by id
                $("#<%= txtChosenTime.ClientID %>").val("zoo text")

                alert("Text of text box = " + $("#<%= txtChosenTime.ClientID %>").val() )

                // select control by class
                $(".mycool").text("zoo text")

                alert("Text of label = " + $("#<%= Label1.ClientID %>").text() )

            }


        </script>
```

Note that for:

a asp.net text box, you use .val() (to get, or set). Don't forget the "()"

for a asp.net label, you use .text() (to get or set).

So, I would probably have written the above as:

```
        <script>
            function myjscode() {

                // select control by id
                var txtTime = $("#<%= txtChosenTime.ClientID %>")
                txtTime.val("zoo text")
                alert("Text of text box = " + txtTime.val() )

                // select control by class
                $(".mycool").text("zoo text")

                alert("Text of label = " + $("#<%= Label1.ClientID %>").text() )
            }

        </script>
```

So, when using jQuery, you use a "method" of that jQuery object, and that getter and setter is thus .val()

```
  .val() gets the value
  .val("some text here") sets the value of the text box.
```

As noted, for a label, you use .text().

And, I often since I am somewhat lazy?

I often set the client id = "static", which means for the asp.net processing to NOT change the id of the control.

So, I often do this:

```
        <asp:Textbox ID="txtChosenTime" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Textbox>
        <br />
```

And now my code becomes this:

```
            function myjscode() {

                // select control by id
                var txtTime = $("#txtChosenTime")
                txtTime.val("zoo text")
                alert("Text of text box = " + txtTime.val() )
```

So, since you "often" has to use that "messy" server side expression to get the correct "id", then I often just as dropping in the text box (or label), add into the markup the clientidmode="static". As a result, then the jQuery code becomes quite a be more clean, and no <%= .ClientID %> expression is required.

Also, note the 2nd code in which I set a value of a label. the VERY cool feature of jQuery is that you can select multiple elements, and then the .val()/.text() will apply to ALL of the elements you match on the page (and wild card selectors are allowed!!).

So, I could have actually written the code this way:

```
        <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">

        </asp:Textbox>
        <br />
        <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">

        </asp:Textbox>
        <br />
        <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox3" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">

        </asp:Textbox>
        <br />



        <script>
            function myjscode() {

                // select control by id
                var txtTime = $("#Textbox1, #Textbox2, Textbox3 ")
                txtTime.val("zoo text")
```

So, I set 3 text boxes in one shot!!!

And as noted, wild cards are allowed, so I could do this:

```
        <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">

        </asp:Textbox>
        <br />
        <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">

        </asp:Textbox>
        <br />
        <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox3" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">

        </asp:Textbox>
        <br />



        <script>
            function myjscode() {

                // select control by id
                var txtTime = $('[id^=Textbox]')
                txtTime.val("zoo text")
```

So, the jQuery selector not limited to "operating" against one control as a result of the jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues.

1. You're trying to select by ID, but your selector omits the ID selector prefix, `#`
2. You're attempting to use `.value` on a jQuery object, rather than `.val()`.

Try this:

```
const $txtChosenTime = $("#<%=txtChosenTime.ClientID%>");
console.info($txtChosenTime.val());
```

Alternatively, if this element **will not be repeated**, you can avoid concerning yourself with server IDs entirely, and add `ClientIdMode="static"` to the element to preserve its assigned ID:

```
<asp:Textbox ID="txtChosenTime" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static"></asp:Textbox>
```

```
$("#txtChosenTime").val();
```